# Set State Hooks with array and objetcs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> ```
> ***Basically I want to put this state, but I don't know what the initial state will be because when I use setState it doesn't change my
> ```
>
> state.
> The state I want to set will be an array with two objects and inside them there are two properties that received another array

---

```
   let GraphFilteEvent = queryEventTimelineFilteredAPI(eventdate).then(ret => {
                const current = []
                const date = []
                const date2 = []
                const past = []
                if (ret === undefined) { } else {
                    
                    const diff = (eventdate.to - eventdate.from)
                    const diffrt  = timeConversion(diff)
                    const diff_string = diffrt.slice(0, 1)
                    const raw = JSON.parse(ret)
                   
    
                    raw.slice(0, diff_string).forEach((elem, i ) => {
                        current.unshift({ x: elem.day, y: elem.sum })
                        date.unshift({ z: elem.date })
                        
    
                    })
    
                    raw.slice(diff_string).forEach((elem, i ) => {
                        past.unshift({ x: elem.day, y: elem.sum })
                        
                        date2.unshift({ z: elem.date}
    
                    })

             }) 
 
            const retvalor = [{data: current, date: date },{data: past , date: date2}]
            setGraphState(retvalor)
            console.log(retvalor)
            
            console.log(graphState)

       
    promiseArray.push(GraphFilteEvent)

            Promise.all(promiseArray).then(value => {

                setLoading(true)
            })
        }
```

}

This is full code with promisse.

Some erros in the scope were my copy and past for the stackover flow attetion on the set state with promisse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
const [graphState, setGraphState] = useState([{ data: current, date: date 
},{data: past , date: date2}])


const retvalor = [{data: current, date: date },{data: past , date: date2}]

setGraphState(prev=> retvalor )
```

Comment: I tried to user this but it didn't work the problem I believe it is because I'm trying to put an array with objects that varied a lot from the initial state.

const [graphState, setGraphState] = useState([{ data: [{x : 1, y: ""}], date: [{z: ""}] },{data: [{x: 1, y: ""}] , date: [{z : ""}]}])

is like this but not change

Comment: The setGraphState is asynchronous. So your console will print before updating the `graphState`. You can try adding to in you code `useEffect(()=>{ console.log(graphState) },[graphState])` . it will console the data when `graphState` gets updated.

Comment: Ooooh! Great Thanks Fathma! see now the graphState is set now. 
Now i can use to change my graphs

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the state inside some onclick or onchange function or inside promis

Comment: Yes, is a promisse function, i need waiting promisse finished for user? Se full code i gonne edit